# How to make an embed defined?

Tags: module, discord.js, token, undefined, embed

The problem with my code is that I have two errors at the moment. "Syntax Error: Unexpected Token "." even though the "." is part of the code and should be working fine. Then another when I get rid of the "." is "Reference Error: fairyEmbed is not defined" Here's the code in question:

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = fairyEmbed;
    .setColor('#dd525d')
    .setTitle('Fairy')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/0K6qBmnRizU')
    .setDescription('Fairy types are too cutesy for my preference. They’re weak to Poison and Steel type and Fire, Steel and Poison types resist their attacks. But they do a lot of damage to Dark, Fighting and Dragon types. Dragon type attacks don’t effect them at all, so they’re good in that department.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F627055948095995745%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Vu5xwOk0k9tBEJ9Yclz2F&ust=1609622152653000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCICQ3vXT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')

module.exports = fightingEmbed;
    .setColor('#61dde6')
    .setTitle('Fighting')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/FJgRlbjzsrs')
    .setDescription('Fighting types are very resilient. Their attacks are super effective against Rock, Steel, Dark, Normal and Ice types and they resist Dark, Rock and Bug type attacks. Fighting type attacks won’t do well against Flying, Psychic, Fairy, Poison or Bug types and they won’t do anything to Ghost types and they’re very weak to Fairy, Psychic and Flying type attacks.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpokemon.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FZamazenta_(anime)&psig=AOvVaw1b8V8kCknIyef2c_zxuFjV&ust=1609622421791000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJCsvPXU--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAM')

module.exports = steelEmbed;
    .setColor('#ba2838')
    .setTitle('Steel')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/I_57ptO3TKc')
    .setDescription('Steel types are the prime definition of defense with an amazing resistance to Normal, Grass, Ice, Flying, Psychic, Bug, Rock, Dragon, Steel and Fairy type attacks and are immune to Poison attacks. They’ll do immense damage to Rock, Fairy and Ice types. If they get hit by Fire, Ground or Fighting type attacks, they’ll be greatly damaged and they don’t do much to Water, Fire, Electric or other Steel types.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpokemongohub.net%2Fpost%2Fguide%2Fdialga-heat-map%2F&psig=AOvVaw3l68mb5ltZZZusGgHSGLTd&ust=1609622768057000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjLpZ_W--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAV')

module.exports = darkEmbed;
    .setColor('#3a4c7b')
    .setTitle('Dark')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/0K6qBmnRizU')
    .setDescription('Dark type Pokémon are masters of the night and dirty, underhanded tactics. They’re very strong against Psychic and Ghost and resist Dark and Ghost type attacks. Psychic type attacks don’t stand a chance due to their immunity. It’s best to avoid putting them against Fighting, Fairy and Bug type attacks because of their weakness and they won’t do as much damage against Dark, Fighting and Fairy type Pokémon. Either way you slice it, Dark type Pokémon are very strong. Spikemuth’s gym is a prime example of that.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbulbapedia.bulbagarden.net%2Fwiki%2FYveltal_(Pok%25C3%25A9mon)&psig=AOvVaw01HxoY93uTikkUD-yDrdJU&ust=1609623455517000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIDG2OLY--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')

module.exports = dragonEmbed;
    .setColor('#352822')
    .setTitle('Dragon')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/8lrMjcNJGfE')
    .setDescription('Dragon types are very rare and thought to be a mystical type. If you want to stop them in their tracks, use Fairy, Ice or Dragon type moves against them. Dragon types resist Fire, Water, Grass and Electric type attacks and Dragon Type attacks are only strong against themselves but have a wide variety of attacks. Dragons type moves don’t do much to Steel types and Fairy types are completely immune to their attacks. My bro said Raihan was infamous for completely demolishing trainers with his overwhelming dragons, so I’d watch your choices around them.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbleedingcool.com%2Fgames%2Frayquaza-raid-guide-how-to-catch-a-shiny-rayquaza-in-pokemon-go%2F&psig=AOvVaw02L1u59NkP3kqQSp5xAJKB&ust=1609623775222000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIiX9PvZ--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')
```

My goal for this code is to send an embed with a different file. That's the embed file which isn't working. I've tried removing the "." and googling ways to define embeds and so on but nothing helpful comes up. All that shows is an embed documentation which doesn't answer how to fix my errors directly or what I should've done. So here I am.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the Embeds like:

```js
 const Discord = require("discord.js");
 let fairyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setColor('#dd525d')
 .setTitle('Fairy')
 .setURL('https://youtu.be/0K6qBmnRizU')
 .setDescription('Fairy types are too cutesy for my preference. They’re weak to Poison and Steel type and Fire, Steel and Poison types resist their attacks. But they do a lot of damage to Dark, Fighting and Dragon types. Dragon type attacks don’t effect them at all, so they’re good in that department.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
 .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F627055948095995745%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Vu5xwOk0k9tBEJ9Yclz2F&ust=1609622152653000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCICQ3vXT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')
```

you have to do this for every single embed. The solution that you have cannot work, because from where should your program know that `fairyEmbed` for example is a MessageEmbed? Defining means storing values in variables. In this case our values are MessageEmbeds. If you defined it, your program is able to know that you are working with embeds. And then you can do:

```js
module.exports = fairyEmbed;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do what you are attempting to do :)

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.fairyEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Title!')
    .setDescription('Hello World!');
```